# C# How can I get a list of country codes?

Tags: c#, mobile, populate, country-codes

I need to know how can I get the list of country codes for mobile purposes, 
for eg, I am living in Singapore and my country code is (65). If I want to send a sms
or call a number, I will specify +65 98287222.

Edited: Is there any codes available to populate this list of country calling codes?

I am using C#, windows application.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There's a huge list of country calling codes on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes) which you could use.

Answer (score 1):

here is a link you may find useful
http://www.countrycodes.com/call.php

Answer (score 1):

A Bing search turns up all sorts of places where you can download a list.  I bet adding "Web Service" to the search criteria would return a bunch of web services you can call to get the list.

http://www.bing.com/search?q=country+codes+list&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC

*Edit - added*

Yep.  Adding "Web Service" found better links. Here's the first:

http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx

Answer (score 0):

You can use my package [`Nager.Country`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.Country). It is available via nuget. The object contain a property callingCodes.

```
PM> install-package Nager.Country
```

```cs
ICountryProvider countryProvider = new CountryProvider();
var countryInfo = countryProvider.GetCountry(Alpha2Code.SG);

//countryInfo.callingCodes = 65
```